# Parse cloud code Console. Authorization failure

Tags: parse-platform

When I try to follow the tutorial at Cloud Code Guide, it says to create a new app with parse and login. After entering my user name and password, it says "Authorization Failed." I'm sure I'm using the correct email and password. I am using my gmail account. what can be the problem?

Comment: related [parse.exe not seeing my projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578396/parse-exe-not-seeing-my-projects)

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

v2.1.3 fixes the issue for me.

---

I had a similar issue when running `parse.exe` through Windows command prompt.

When running it through Windows Power Shell (using `ParseDeploy.exe`) it authenticated fine.