# parse.exe not seeing my projects

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to configure my machine to deploy Parse Cloud Code. This requires downloading and running `ParseDeploy.exe`, followed by `parse new`.

I am running Win 8.1, and using the latest `parse-windows-2.0.7.exe`.

The folder structure is correctly created.

After entering my email & password, I am meant to see a list of my apps. Instead I am seeing:

```
1: results 
Select an App:
```

"results" is not the name of any of my 3 apps.

---

This is what the PowerShell output looks like:

```
PS E:\...\demo> parse new
Creating a new project in directory E:\...\demo\parse
Creating directory E:\...\demo\parse\config
Creating config file E:\...\demo\parse\config\global.js
on
Creating directory E:\...\demo\parse\cloud
Writing out sample file E:\...\demo\parse\cloud\main.js

Creating directory E:\...\demo\parse\public
Writing out sample file E:\...\demo\parse\public\index.
html
Email: richard@glowworm.mobi
Password:
1: results
Select an App:
```

---

Related post:

- [Parse: No list of apps from Parse in CTL windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438665/parse-no-list-of-apps-from-parse-in-ctl-windows-7)

---

I have used this successfully on previous projects. What has changed?

Answer (score 1):

Some very old versions of the Parse command line utility may run into this issue due to some backend changes. You can get around this issue by making sure you're running the latest version of the command line utility, available at https://parse.com/docs/downloads

I also recommend joining the Parse developer mailing list, where we made an announcement a couple of weeks ago recommending that people make sure they update their command line utility prior to the backend change going into effect: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/WoRnDft4qmE

Comment: v2.1.3 fixes the issue on my side.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

v2.1.3 fixes this issue, and works correctly on my machine.

---

What has changed? Parse has made updates, requiring a new version of parse.exe to be downloaded.

Unfortunately the initial new versions do not work.

---

### Workaround

I have rolled back to using v1.4.2 of `parse.exe`.

It is currently working for deploying projects.

However, it breaks when creating a new project with `parse new` (as per my question).

The file that breaks is `.\config\global.json` - it seems to be in a new format, and it tries to reference this non-existent "results" project.

What I have done is to an existing global.json file from an older project, and manually edit it to update the values for my new project. Here is an example:

```
{
  "global": {
    "parseVersion": "1.4.2"
  },
  "applications": {
    "<< AppName >>": {
      "applicationId": "<< app id >>",
      "masterKey": "<< master key >>"
    },
    "_default": {
      "link": "<< AppName >>"
    }
  }
}
```

Just update the following fields:

- << AppName >>
- << app id >>
- << master key >>

*(works as of 2 June 2015)*

---

### Bug Reported

A bug has been opened related to this issue on Facebook Developers:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/971635999542789/

The following versions are not running on my machine:

- v2.0.7
- v2.0.8
- v2.0.9

There are other reports [on the support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/WoRnDft4qmE) that these versions are broken for other people as well.

---